# MSXML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

This code works well in good old VB6.  I have tried all kinds of ways to do this in VB.NET but can't get it to work.  Can anyone help me with code that works in .NET please?

```
Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Dim strReturn As String
Dim objReturn As New MSXML2.DOMDocument


Dim url As String
Dim XMLEnvelope As String


url = "http://zzzzzdummy.com"

XMLEnvelope = vbNull



objHTTP.open("post", url, False, "", "")  '

Debug.Print(Err.Number)

objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-length", Len(XMLEnvelope))
Debug.Print("------------Send Envelope-------------")
Debug.Print(XMLEnvelope)
Debug.Print("--------------------------------------")
objHTTP.send(XMLEnvelope)

strReturn = objHTTP.responseText
objReturn.loadXML(strReturn)
Debug.Print("----------Response Envelope-----------")
Debug.Print(strReturn)
Debug.Print("--------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Have you seen the `System.Xml` namespace?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with.  The response from this I can then go into the XML return and parse it.

```
Function WRequest(ByVal URL As String, ByVal method As String, ByVal POSTdata As String) As String
     Dim responseData As String = ""

     Try
         Dim hwrequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
         hwrequest.Accept = "*/*"
         hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
         hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1"
         hwrequest.Timeout = 60000
         hwrequest.Method = method

         If hwrequest.Method = "POST" Then
             hwrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

             Dim encoding As New Text.ASCIIEncoding() 'Use UTF8Encoding for XML requests
             Dim postByteArray() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(POSTdata)
             hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length

             Dim postStream As IO.Stream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream()
             postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length)
             postStream.Close()

         End If

         Dim hwresponse As Net.HttpWebResponse = hwrequest.GetResponse()
         If hwresponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
             Dim responseStream As IO.StreamReader =  New IO.StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
             responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
         End If

         hwresponse.Close()
     Catch e As Exception
         responseData = "An error occurred: " & e.Message
     End Try
     Return responseData

 End Function
```

Comment: +1: pretty good, but you should add `Using` blocks around your `Stream`, `StreamReader` and `WebResponse` instances, and you'd do better to let the exception propagate rather than return it as a string that tells nobody what the exception was.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use MSXML in a .NET application. The classes in the various `System.Xml` namespaces are more powerful and easier to use. They are also likely to have a much longer useful lifetime.

You're actually lucky to be using VB.NET. It has built-in handling of XML via XML literals and LINQ to XML.

---

Actually, your code does not include any processing of XML. You should simply use the `WebClient` or `WebRequest` classes.

Comment: I dont want to use this in NET, I was just trying to find the code that does does the same thing in .NET