# RESTful API request works in Python and browser but not in VB.Net

Tags: python, vb.net, rest

I want to call a RESTful API with the following call

```
https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D..EUR.SP00.A?updatedAfter=2018-08-01T07%3A05%3A02%2B07%3A05&startPeriod=2018-08-01&detail=dataonly&dimensionAtObservation=TIME_PERIOD
```

The result should be an XML containing currency exchange rates.

I need to get this to work in vb.net, but it does not work (anymore). A few days ago it still worked. I use the following code:

```vb
Try
    ' define webclient settings
    Dim _webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient

    ' I tried with and without the following line
    ' _webClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36"

    Dim link as String = "https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D..EUR.SP00.A?updatedAfter=2018-08-01T07%3A05%3A02%2B07%3A05&startPeriod=2018-08-01&detail=dataonly&dimensionAtObservation=TIME_PERIOD"
    Dim sourceString As String = _webClient.DownloadString(link)

Catch ex As Exception
    ' Error in request url or on the server side
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd hh:mm:ss") & " Error: " & ex.Message)
```

The `ex.message` then contains the following info:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

However, the very same request works in my browser when copy & pasted to the address bar and in Python. I use the following Python code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D..EUR.SP00.A?updatedAfter=2018-08-01T07%3A05%3A02%2B07%3A05&startPeriod=2018-08-01&detail=dataonly&dimensionAtObservation=TIME_PERIOD'

response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code) #returns 200
```

What is the error in the VB.Net code? What is the difference?

Comment: Did you want vba or vb.Net? The above is .Net? I have given a VBA answer. If only .Net I will delete so please advise.

Comment: See the following for .Net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491052/msxml-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what the error was. I have to set the `Accept` Header as follows:

```
_webClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Accept) = "*/*"
```

Then it works.